# Is yes or no correct as buttons to answer: are you sure you want to cancel

Tags: html

I have this button, when the user presses cancel a dialog box appear and asks: Are you sure you want to cancel?

Which is considered as correct buttons for it: Yes/No or Cancel/Ok

Comment: Are you sure you want to cancel? Yes/No. It's a simple question requiring a yes or no answer, the same as "Would you like a beer?"

Comment: i don't think there is a 'correct' way, its whatever you think will make it easiest on your user. i would tend to lean towards `Yes/No` but that's just me

Comment: Take a look at this: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35753/what-to-call-cancel-when-cancel-is-already-the-default-action and/or http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9946/should-i-use-yes-no-or-ok-cancel-on-my-message-box/9956#9956

Answer (score 2):

If the question is:

> Are you sure you want to cancel?

And the answers are:

> [OK]  [Cancel]

Don't you think that would be a little confusing?  If I click "OK" am I agreeing to "Cancel"?  If I click "Cancel" does that mean I *don't* want to "Cancel"?

The question being asked is a yes/no question.  It should have yes/no answers.  Or, even better, specifically descriptive buttons.  For example, if the user is pressing "Cancel" on a form they're filling out, the dialog could be something like:

> This will cancel the form.  Are you sure?
>
> [Cancel the form]  [Return to the form]

Then the user is invoking a specific action, and just re-iterating the invocation of that action instead of answering a new question.

Comment: This is what Skype does.  It's a perfect example of what *not* to do: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9946/should-i-use-yes-no-or-ok-cancel-on-my-message-box/9956#9956

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're not confusing the user then "yes/no" is perfectly fine.